# How to fix a syntax error when trying to output two items

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to get the radius of a circle as an output while inputting the area but I keep getting a syntax error in the last line. please help this keeps happening on alot of my programs when I try to output two items.

I've tried many solutions that I know

```
area = int(input ("Enter area of a circle: "))

pi = int(3.1416)

radius = (area/pi) ** (1/2)

print ("Radius of a circle with area", area "is", radius)
```

I keep getting a invalid syntax error right after the `"is"` in the last line before the `, radius`.

Comment: You are missing a ``,`` between ``area`` and ``"is"``.

Comment: Take note that ``pi = int(3.1416)`` is equal to ``pi = 3``, which is very, very, wrong. Use ``pi = 3.1416`` or ``import math`` and then use ``math.pi``.

Answer (score 2):

- You're missing a comma between `area` and `"is"` in the `print` function.
- `int(3.1416)` is equal to `3`, use `math.pi` instead of defining your own `pi`.
- Use `math.sqrt` instead of `** (1 / 2)`.
- Use `float` instead of `int` for the `area`.

---

```
from math import pi, sqrt

area = float(input("Enter area of a circle: "))

radius = sqrt(area / pi)

print ("Radius of a circle with area", area, "is", radius)
```